# How we can Iterate within a particular row with known index in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame named df_cp which has the data as below,
[image]

I need to insert a new project name for CompanyID 'LCM' at the first empty cell in a row with index 1. I have found the index of the row which is of my interest using this,

```
index_row = df_cp[df_cp['CompanyID']=='LCM'].index
```

How can I iterate within a row with index_row as 1, the task is to replace the first NaN at index 1 with "Healthcare".

Please help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `isna` and `idxmax`:

```
df.loc[1, df.loc[1].isna().idxmax()] = 'Healthcare'
```

Output:

```
  CompanyID Project01  Project02 Project03   Project04  Project05
0       134       oil  furniture       NaN         NaN        NaN
1       LCM       oil  furniture       car  Healthcare        NaN
2       Z01       oil  furniture       NaN         NaN        NaN
3       453       oil  furniture      agro        meat        NaN
```

Note:  idxmax returns the index of the first occurrence of the maximum value.

More, generalized:

```
m = df['CompanyID'] == 'LCM'
df.loc[m, df[m].isna().idxmax(axis=1)] = 'Healthcare'
df
```

Output:

```
  CompanyID Project01  Project02 Project03   Project04  Project05
0       134       oil  furniture       NaN         NaN        NaN
1       LCM       oil  furniture       car  Healthcare        NaN
2       Z01       oil  furniture       NaN         NaN        NaN
3       453       oil  furniture      agro        meat        NaN
```